# 19.10 dhclient + resolvconf not updating resolv.conf

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp

I am *not* running systemd.resolved, not do I wish to.
Am am using netplan, systemd.networkd, resolvconf, dhclient
`/etc/resolv.conf` is a link -> `../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`
The resolvconf hook from the resolvconf package is in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/resolvconf`

The problem is resolv.conf is not being properly populated from the DHCP server and just contains the boilerplate comment header from resolvconf.

What else am I missing to have /etc/resolv.conf properly populated from dhcp?

Please note:
- I do not wish to manually or statically configure
- I do not wish to run systemd.resolved

Update:
I think I've probably 95% answered my question since asking after poking around more. First off, dhclient is not used in this case because systemd.networkd uses its own DHCP client, and does not apparently provide any obvious way to hook it to take actions like, say, create an /etc/resolv.conf. It appears the only way to use full DHCP configuration is to also run resolved, which is quite unfortunate.

Comment: Are you running a desktop or server installation? In resolv.conf you probably see 127.0.0.53, yes? Any particular reason not to run systemd.resolved, and to run with netplan?

Comment: _did_ see 127.0.0.53 until I disabled systemd.resolved, as expected. This is ubuntu server (there's no UI installed either).

I have reasons for not wanting to take up port 53 and run a local DNS cache, and yes, this is a valid thing to want to do.

Comment: Yes, use netplan if you're running a server. If you're running a full dnsmasq at the same time, there's a parameter in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf so that two system resources don't try and tie up port 53 at the same time. Is that why? Otherwise, I can't think of any reason to disable a part of the OS.